# NetBeans as an editor for ColdFusion scripts?

Tags: netbeans, plugins, coldfusion

Is there any known NetBeans plug-in for editing, formatting and colour-coding of ColdFusion scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid not.  Some people have hacked together very basic syntax coloring and proper comments, but no plugin, and no cfml support.

Your best bet is the eclipse based [CFEclipse](http://www.cfeclipse.org/) or Adobe's [ColdFusion Builder](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/coldfusionbuilder/) beta.

Also if you like [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org/) I've had good results with that as well.

I know you asked about Netbeans but seriously unless things have changed you are better off elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) and [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) have code coloring as add-ons (ColdFusion for [Sublime](https://github.com/SublimeText/ColdFusion) and [Netbeans](http://bigkidsdidit.co.uk/coldfusion-language-in-notepad)), and you can get code completion for java functions, but you can't run the code like java in NetBeans, CFEclispse - mentioned above - can do that I think, but I have yet to get that to work (takes more time and devotion than I have to spare).

I prefer sublime because it's a little more customizable than Notepad++, but they're both great options, and lighter than Dreamweaver.

PS: Both Sublime and Notepad are free, but sublime wants you to spend $60, and reminds you every once in a while, which is kinda annoying, but I still use it over everything else.

Comment: > (ColdFusion for Sublime and Netbeans),
s/Netbeans/Notepad++/

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of IntelliJ IDEA. The ColdFusion plugin has its warts, but it's pretty good, as its Javascript, and I love the overall editor experience. It has support for tons of other languages too. http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Comment: This is an old answer but I must stress that IntelliJ IDEA is the best CFML (ColdFusion) IDE that I have used thus far.

Comment: Just keep in mind that you need the Ultimate edition which can be quite expensive.