# Netbeans - How to extend HTML vocabulary

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9

I've been using netbeans for a couple of years now, mainly on PHP / CakePHP projects.

Recently I've started using Coldfusion, which isn't directly supported. I've found, however, that if I use PHP as a project type, I can load the files and the HTML Renderer does an admirable job with the Coldfusion tags.

I want to make it better and help the renderer to  understand some of the tags and, hopefully, thereby improve code indentation and syntax highlighting.

My question, then, is how can I access the HTML dictionary to extend the vocabulary?

**NB: This isn't a 'which IDE' question so don't recommend them. I want to know if and how I can achieve this in NetBeans and only Netbeans.**

Comment: I would recommend to consider the alternatives, otherwise you may feel much more incomfortable with the language. Please this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392934/netbeans-as-an-editor-for-coldfusion-scripts/1400473#1400473

Comment: The alternatives are Eclipse and DreamWeaver. Two of the worst (in my opinion) IDEs on the planet. I feel extremely uncomfortable with both of them.

Comment: It sounds like you just want a basic text editor with some syntax highlighting then, Leo.  If you want that, then go with Vim with the ColdFusion syntax file.

Comment: Dave - read the question, particularly the last two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few ideas.  If you render it in HTML, you could probably add a custom name space to the HTML.  If setup correctly it can help NetBeans realize that the tags are valid and shouldn't show as an error. It might not give you all the preview and WYSIWYG functionality, but it may be better than what you are getting now. I have only done this on other platforms, but I'm pretty sure NetBeans supports it.

Also I think that NetBeans will let you add CustomTags doing something like this:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/CustomTagActions

Comment: This is getting closer, thanks. The link looks very interesting. I'm beginning to wonder if I should set this up as a project on GitHub or Google or somewhere. Maybe a full-blown Coldfusion plugin could be developed that way.

Answer (score 0):

Just to note, in terms of ColdFusion the other alternatives are [NotePad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with the [CF plugin](http://howardscholz.wordpress.com/2007/06/01/notepad-support-for-coldfusion-8/) and [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) now [supports](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/coldfusion-2.html) CF.

I really like Eclipse - the number of plugins available (SVN, Javascript, CSS, CodCollab, Flashbuilder etc.) is what makes it indispensable IMHO.

I am, however, looking forward to the [new version of CFBuilder](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2010/10/27/ColdFusion-Builder-2-Storm--Sneak-Peak).

Comment: I found IntelliJ today which is what prompted me to ask this question. Unfortunately, th CF plugin is only available with the paid-for release and it isn't cheap for the licence I'd require.

Comment: I found IntelliJ today which is what promted me to ask this Q. Notepad is out because I need cross-platform. Eclipse I find overweight, unbelievably slow, non-intuitive and developed by people with big beards who eschew mouse users. But I wasn't asking which IDE, I was asking a specific Netbeans Question.

Answer (score 0):

This answer on the same/similar question suggests that there is nothing out there for ColdFusion on netbeans : [NetBeans as an editor for ColdFusion scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392934/netbeans-as-an-editor-for-coldfusion-scripts)

If you want to build your own ColdFusion plugin for netbeans you need to look at plugin development; http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/60/nbm-google.html  You could use the Dictionary project from cfeclipse as a basis for your plugin. See this [Google Group thread](http://groups.google.com/group/cfeclipse-users/browse_thread/thread/7c13bfdd6397212b/e1bd8c47219b6282) for a bit more information

Comment: I'm well aware that no plugin currently exists. My question is not about a Coldfusion plugin, either available or to build, but is about extending the HTML dictionary.